# How can I exclude the 10 from the output?

Tags: c

How can I exclude the "10" from the output?

**Code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[2] ,*j, *k;
    printf ("Enter the Minimum value: ");
    scanf ("%d" , &num[0]);
    printf ("Enter the Maximum Value: ");
    scanf ("%d" , &num[1]);

    j = &num[0], k = &num[1];

    printf("The maximum Numbers are: ");

    while ((*j < *k) && (*j != *k))
    {
         ++(*j);
         printf(" %d" , *j);
    }

    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

Enter the Minimum value: 1

Enter the Maximum Value: 10

The maximum Numbers are:  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 **10**

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Just put the `++(*j)` after the `printf`.

Comment: @KfirVentura But that will then print `1` at the beginning of the list - which is not what the OP wants, it seems.

Comment: @AdrianMole `*j != *k` would take care of that

Comment: @M.Kotzjan How? On the first run through the loop (with the given example), `*j` is 1 and `*k` is 10. The `*j != *k` is entirely redundant.

Comment: @AdrianMole oh, you are right. Never mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer only one condition to exit a loop.
It's more easy to understand.

```
while ( *j < (*k - 1) )
{
     ++(*j);
     printf(" %d" , *j);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pre-increment the `*j` value in the actual test condition of the `while` loop; also, you don't need the `!=` test, as that will already be included in the `<` comparison:

```c
    while (++(*j) < *k) {
        printf(" %d", *j);
    }
```